# Superimpose plots Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have two signals, one for each axis and taken singularly and plotted in a standard way separately they would look like this:

[image]
[image]

However they represent different measurements and I need to superimpose them by representing one on the standard X-Y axis (bottom-left) and one on a different set of coordinate axis (X = left, Y = top).

I thought of the following code:

```
    figure(1); 
    line(1:128,imagesXMatrix(i,:));
    ax1 = gca;
    set(ax1,'XColor','r','YColor','r')
    ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'), ...
          'XAxisLocation','left','YAxisLocation','top', ...
          'Color', 'none','XColor','k','YColor','k');
    line(1:128,imagesYMatrix(i,:),'Parent',ax2);
```

but am getting the following error:

> Error using axes
>
> Bad property value found.
>
> Object Name: axes Property
>
> Name: 'XAxisLocation'.

which I guess means that value `left` is not ok for the `XAxisLocation` variable.

What I would really want is simply the superimposition of the two following plots, any idea on how to make it happen?

[image]
[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your X-Axis is per definition the one in the top or botton, and your Y-Axis the one on the left or right. You have to swap X and Y.

Comment: @DanielR - I see, can you help me understand how to do it?Thanks again!

Comment: possible duplicate of [plotting two yaxis with different markers and colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142386/plotting-two-yaxis-with-different-markers-and-colors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plotyy` will do the trick:

```
figure(1) 
AX = plotyy(x1,y1,x2,y2,'plot'); 

set(get(AX(1),'Ylabel'),'String','y1') 
set(get(AX(2),'Ylabel'),'String','y2')
```

and additional properties like:

```
set(AX(1),'ylim',[...],...) 
set(AX(2),'ylim',[...],...)
```

and more information in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but I'm still a bit confuse on how to apply this to my problem. Isn't `plotyy` only allowing me to plot 2 signals by using same `x`?  If not how can I actually obtain the superimposition?

Comment: the two signals appear in the same plot, or what do you mean by superimposition? do you want 2 x-axes? then you need to have a look at `subplot`

Comment: you can also use two different `x` with `plotyy`

Comment: It worked! I just needed to do some tuning on the limits of the two axis.

Comment: Yep using different x was the solution.